# $(".class").on('click', function () but not if it has $('class2') (child class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I need to have an onclick function for `$(.playbox')` but not if `$('mp3buy')` is pressed `$(.mp3buy')` is child of `$('.playbox')` so if I click `$('mp3buy')` its as if I click `$(.playbox')`

I have tried:

```
$(".playbox").not('mp3buy').on('click', function ()
```

and I also tried putting the following if statement within the function but then the function wont perform:

```
$(".playbox").on('click', function () {
    if (this.hasClass('mp3buy')){
        //do nothing
    } else {
    $(".playerbottom").removeClass("noclick");
    $(".inlinethinger").removeClass("noclick");
    var key = $(this).find(".play").attr('key');
    var name = $(this).find(".play").attr('name');
    window.nowplay = $(this).find(".play");// variable for now playing class .play
    window.nowplay2 = $(this); 
    EvalSound(this, key);
    $(".play").not(this).removeClass("pause");
    $(".play").not(this).parent().parent().removeClass('playboxplaylight');
    $(".play").not(this).parent().removeClass("greenback");    
    $(this).find(".play").toggleClass("pause");
    $(this).find(".play").parent().parent().toggleClass('playboxplaylight');
    $(this).find(".play").parent().toggleClass("greenback");
    $(this).find(".play").hasClass("pause") ? $(".playerbottom").addClass("pausebottom") : $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
    $(".nowplayingname").text(name);
    $(".playerbottom").on('click', function () {
    $(this).find(".play").hasClass("pausebottom") ? nowplay.addClass("pause") : nowplay.removeClass("pause");

 }); 
    }
});
```

I am wondering if there is a simple way to rule out a child class within an onclick function?

Comment: You're missing the dot in your css selector: `$(".playbox").not('.mp3buy').on('click', function () {....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="playbox">
    <div class="mp3buy">
        ... content ...
    </div>
</div>
```

You can set a handler on `.mp3buy` and make use of `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
$(".mp3buy").on("click", function(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
    // Any clicks on .mp3buy will not be passed to .playbox's click handler.
});

$(".playbox").on("click", function() {
    // Normal functionality here
});
```

```js
$(".mp3buy").on("click", function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  alert("mp3buy click handler called");
});

$(".playbox").on("click", function() {
  alert("playbox click handler called");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playbox">
  .playbox content
  <div class="mp3buy">
    .mp3buy content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Art! I never knew of event.stopPropagation() (Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree), this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to test the event target element against your class:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".playbox").on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.mp3buy')) {
      // do nothing
      return;
    }
    // do your stuff
    alert('ok');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="playbox" style="width: 300px;height: 300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <button class="mp3buy" style="position:relative;top: 40%;left: 40%;">ClickMe</button>
</div>
```